# Exception with UITableViewCell. EXC_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am creating my custom UITableViewCell, without using IB or Storyboard. The UITableViewCell needs to be of the Subtitle style. 
When I used the base class, UITableViewCell I find the cell to have the default style rather than the subtitle style I need. 
I think this is happening because in tableview:cellforrowatindexpath, the method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is returning a cell of the default type, maybe this was because the init method of class UITableViewCell is returning the default style.

So I decided to subclass UITableViewCell and within the init method of the subclass (MyTableViewCell), I set the style to be of type Subtitle.

The main code snippets are as below:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CellSubtitle")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
....
}
```

And within the tableviewcontroller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> MyTableViewCell! {
        let cellIdentifier = "CellSubtitle"

        var cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil   {
            println("Cell is nil so creating a new one")
            cell = MyTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            cell.textLabel.text = " Some text"
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = " Some more text!"
        }
        return cell
    }
```

This seems to throw an exception while dequeueing a cell, as below:
(Any pointers to the root cause is much appreciated)

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x50b5f, 0x001de43e libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 26, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
  * frame #0: 0x001de43e libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 26
    frame #1: 0x00082754 swift2`swift2.MyTableViewController.tableView (tableView=Some, indexPath=Some, self=0x15e4d980)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.UITableView>, cellForRowAtIndexPath : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath>) -> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<swift2.MyTableViewCell> + 1244 at MyTableViewController.swift:52
    frame #2: 0x000835c4 swift2`@objc swift2.MyTableViewController.tableView (swift2.MyTableViewController)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.UITableView>, cellForRowAtIndexPath : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath>) -> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<swift2.MyTableViewCell> + 100 at MyTableViewController.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x3139e8f6 UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 410
    frame #4: 0x31345c26 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1806
```

Edit: If I comment out dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, the crash disappears

Comment: Are you using prototype cells in your storyboard?  If so, what style have you selected?

Comment: @Paulw11 I want to do this without using storyboard or XIB files. So no prototype cells in storyboard.

Comment: Have you called `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` on your tableView?  You should never receive a nil cell from `dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` if you have.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I did registerClass in the viewdidload. And yes it was surprising to me that I never received a nil cell from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier [before I subclassed, after subclassing I see the exception], if such is the case is there a method to update the UITableViewCellStyle for the cell returned by this method. If there is, then I would not need to subclass.

Comment: I just created a minimal app that replicates your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the same hard-to-understand error involving swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional when queueing up a collection view cell. It's possible someone else has made the same mistake so here's what happened to me:

In my case, I had two cell classes, each with a xib and a swift class. One was a subclass of the other and was the one that was causing the crash. In the end it turned out that I'd copied the xib from the superclass to add parts to - and I'd failed to change the class of the cell in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder from 'Superclass' to 'Subclass'. Tricky oversight! But that explains the casting error...

Answer (score -1):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> MyTableViewCell! {
    //let cellIdentifier = "CellSubtitle"

    var cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell!
 cell = MyTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier);

    if cell == nil   {
        println("Cell is nil so creating a new one");
 NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@" your CustomCellnib name" owner:nil options:nil];


    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        cell.textLabel.text = " Some text"
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = " Some more text!"
    }
    return cell
}
and make sure that ur nib is a subclass of MyTableViewcell..in Storyboar or in IB
```

Comment: After dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, suppose we get a cell instance. Would not calling MyTableViewCell(style:..., reuseIdentifier: ...) after that create a new instance instead of using the instance returned by dequeueReusable...? 
If cell == nil, you are suggesting to do a loadNibNamed, I wanted to do this without using IB or storyboard, a loadNibNamed would need me to create a xib file right?